# Rails: Rack Rewrite: trailing slash/no trailing slash > new url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rack

Using Rack Rewrite to sort out the redirects moving from Wordpress to Rails. This works fine, as advertised:

```
r301 '/old-url/', '/new-url'
```

But if I type in `/old-url` in the browser, without the trailing slash, it throws an error: `No route matches [GET]`.

What do I need to change to make both the slash and non-slash versions redirect to `/new-url`?

Comment: Maybe a naive question, but could you add `r301 '/old-url', '/new-url'`?  Rewrite rules both with and without the trailing slash?

Comment: I could do, but I have about 800 already, so that would be 1600…

Answer (score 0):

This should match both:

```
r301 '/old-url', '/new-url'
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I can set either `/old-url` or `/old-url/` but neither of them accept the other. The other in each case throws an error.